# Bootstrap 4 (v4.0.0-beta) Transparent Fixed-top Navigation. How to change colour of navbar-collapse menu?

Tags: navbar, transparent

For the responsive nav, ie Logo on left, toggle icon on right.
Id like to have that navbar transparent, 
but the collapsed nav-items with a background colour.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

<!--- TRANSPARENT START--->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
<!--- TRANSPARENT END --->

<!--- COLOURED BG FROM START --->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!--- COLOURED BG END --->

</nav>
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

TY

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your above code is incomplete. In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that removing the "bg-light" calls from the "nav" and creating a media query which will add the style only to the collapsed "nav-items"

```css
 @media (max-width: 988px) {
  .navbar-nav {
   background-color: #e3e3e3;
   padding: 0 10px;
                        margin-top: 5px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">

<!--- TRANSPARENT START--->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
<!--- TRANSPARENT END --->

<!--- COLOURED BG FROM START --->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!--- COLOURED BG END --->

</nav>
```